# Modifying a MOCK_METHOD within a Unit test

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

I have a virtual function defined in the class which is set as `MOCK_METHOD` inside the mock class.

Is it possible to override the `MOCK_METHOD` to change the details of the function?

For example, `SomeFunction` is what I described above, and here the return value is merely set

```
TEST_F(UnitTest, Test)
{
    EXPECT_CALL(*classObject, SomeFunction()).
      WillOnce(Return(true));
}
```

Rather than merely setting its return to some bool, could I modify the function itself within this unit test? So like say invoke a method of `classObject` that returns a bool?

After looking into it, `Invoke` is something that could be used however upon trying the following, I am getting the error `Call to non-static function without an object argument`.

```
TEST_F(UnitTest, Test)
{
    EXPECT_CALL(*classObject, SomeFunction()).
      WillOnce(Invoke(classObject, 
      &ClassObject::SomeClassObjectMethod()));
}
```

Comment: Have you look at [action reference](http://google.github.io/googletest/reference/actions.html)?

Comment: is it the `Invoke` call? When I run this I get an error saying "No matching member. function for call to 'gmock_SomeFunction'`
`EXPECT_CALL(*classObject, SomeFunction()).WillOnce( Invoke(classObject->someClassObjectMethod());`

Comment: Syntax would be `Invoke(classObject, &ClassObject::someClassObjectMethod)`